# Xcode Storyboard not rendering components

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Any component dragged onto the storyboard show as a minimal sized blank view. @IBDrawable not rendering either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall your cuda drivers,

instructions here:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#uninstall

nVIDIA cuda driver seems to conflict with xcode.